# Compare a column with max value of another column in another table

Tags: postgresql

I try to compare a column (date type) from a table like this.

```
id | date
----------
1  | 2020-11-14 05:40:00
2  | 2020-11-15 05:40:00
3  | 2020-11-16 05:40:00
4  | 2020-11-17 05:40:00
5  | 2020-11-18 05:40:00
6  | 2020-11-19 05:40:00
```

to the MAX value of another date type column in another table like this :

```
date
-----
2020-11-12 05:40:00
2020-11-13 05:40:00
2020-11-14 05:40:00
2020-11-15 05:40:00
2020-11-16 05:40:00
```

There is no relational key between the two tables.

So far i tried this but the query keep running without giving any result :

```
SELECT
A.id,
A.date
FROM table1 A 
WHERE A.date > (SELECT MAX(B.date)
FROM table2 B)
LIMIT 1
```

So i should get something like :

```
id | date
----------
4  | 2020-11-17 05:40:00
5  | 2020-11-18 05:40:00
6  | 2020-11-19 05:40:00
```

If i replace the SELECT MAX in the where clause straight by a value, i got a quick response to the query.

Thanks

Comment: please provide sample input and output if possible.

Comment: Do you know what `select max(date) from tableB ` actually returns?

Comment: @Renato yes it returns one row only (same format as the date column from the first table)

Comment: Please ignore limit 1 from your query.

Comment: How many rows does the table B have?